# spring repository - repeated updates

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Im developing an application using spring boot, and spring JPA repositories.

The application logic is simple:

- Get records from an external service
- Check if record exists in my mysql database
- If exists do an update, if not do an insert

This works, but the performance decreases as records are processed.

I enabled mysql logs to watch incoming queries, and I saw lot of repeated updates.

The log entries follows this pattern

1. lot of updates
2. other sentences
3. the same updates in (1) plus more updates
4. other sentences
5. the same updates in (3) plus more updates

Im using a Repository that extends CrudRepository and I do the updates using repository.save() method.

Im trying to save objects of a subclass of Event (using discriminator), those objects have a Hashmap that maps to a JSON column in mysql.

I observed too, that if I only change values in HashMap (without invoking repository.save() method), the database updates are still being invoked.

This is the recurrent code invoked when I get a record from external service:

```
else if (event.getType().equals(EventType.PAYMENT)) {
 PaymentEvent paymentEvent = (PaymentEvent)event;
 PaymentEvent oldPaymentEvent = eventRepository.getPaymentEvent(paymentEvent.getPaymentId(), paymentEvent.getTimestamp());
 if (oldPaymentEvent == null) {
      // save new event
      eventRepository.save(paymentEvent);
 } else {
      // this method updates the internal Hashmap that maps to JSON Column in Mysql
      oldPaymentEvent.updateCustomPropsFrom(paymentEvent);
      // update old event, if I comment this line database updates are still being triggered (modifying internal hashamp in the line above trigger the udpates)
      eventRepository.save(oldPaymentEvent);
}
```

This is the Repository definiton:

```
public interface EventRepository extends CrudRepository<Event, Long> {
}
```

And finally this is the Hashmap merge:

```
public void updateCustomPropsFrom(PaymentEvent event) {
    if (event.getCouponAmount() != null ) {
        this.customProps.put(KEY_COUPON_AMOUNT, event.getCouponAmount());
    }
    if (event.getCurrencyId() != null ) {
        this.customProps.put(KEY_CURRENCY_ID, event.getCurrencyId());
    }
    if (event.getPaymentId() != null ) {
        this.customProps.put(KEY_PAYMENT_ID, event.getPaymentId());
    }
    if (event.getReceivedAmount() != null ) {
        this.customProps.put(KEY_RECEIVED_AMOUNT, event.getReceivedAmount());
    }
    if (event.getPaymentType() != null ) {
        this.customProps.put(KEY_PAYMENT_TYPE, event.getPaymentType());
    }
    if (event.getPaymentReason() != null ) {
        this.customProps.put(KEY_PAYMENT_REASON, event.getPaymentReason());
    }

    if (event.getTimestamp() != null)
        this.setTimestamp(event.getTimestamp());

    if (event.getStoreId()!=null)
        this.setStoreId(event.getStoreId());

    if (event.getUserId()!=null)
        this.setUserId(event.getUserId());

    if (event.getUserId()!=null)
        this.setUserId(event.getUserId());


}
```

I've never faced this problem, can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance. Regards

Comment: Additional information: the update blocks are sorrounded by "SET autocommit=0" in the beggining and "commit, SET autocommit=1" in the ending

Comment: The whole point of JPA is to make changes to managed entities automatically persistent. I can only guess that this is what happens though, since you haven't posted any code.

Comment: I'd agree with @JBNizet. One reason might be that you are editing the entities you already saved again (even setting an attribute to the same value it already has might be sufficient) and thereby trigger another round of updates.

Comment: Thanks for responses .. I've added relevant code to the original post, and I will check the entire code to ensure that already saved objects are not beeing modified again.

Comment: So, I confirm. This is just normal. By design, a managed entity is... managed. Which means any change you make to it is automatically persistent, without any need to call save(), persist(), merge() or whatever.

Comment: That's correct, but the thing is: "why updates to same object are repeating over and over if I only modify them once?" Look at the variable "oldPaymentEvent", this variable points to the existing record but has IF scope, so is never used again.